# Return data from getJSON request and for loop to use in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop, getjson

I am having trouble with a seemingly simple problem. I am pulling data from an external JSON file and need to loop through all the objects and return their values to use in another function. Here is what I have so far...

```
var geo;

function getCountry(){

  $.getJSON('country.json', function(res) {
      $.each(res, function(key, val) {
          for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
              geo = val[i].geometry.coordinates;
              return geo;
          }
      })    
  });
}

function mapIt() {

    getCountry();

    $(".container").mapael({
        map : {
            name : "world_countries", // name of JS file
        },
        plots: {
        'Random': {
            latitude: geo[0],
            longitude: geo[1]
        }               
    }
    });
}

mapIt();
```

Essentially, I am getting the latitude and longitude of a specific country with the first function and am trying to return the value (geo, which is an array containing the lat/long) and use it in the second function. I thought that I could maybe call the getCountry function within the mapIt function and it would store the variable.

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated thank you so much!

EDIT:
Here is some of the JSON:

```
 {
 "world": [
  {
  "properties": {
    "sr_subunit": "Zimbabwe",
    "sr_brk_a3": "ZWE",
    "countries": "ZW",
    "scalerank": 0
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      29.851884620879,
      -19.002536710201
    ]
  }
},
{
 "properties": {
   "sr_subunit": "Samoa",
   "sr_brk_a3": "WSM",
   "countries": "WS",
   "scalerank": 0
 },
 "geometry": {
   "type": "Point",
   "coordinates": [
     -172.404145,
     -13.631557
   ]
  }
 }
]
}
```

Comment: you need to `return` geo outside of the loop, and then set that to a variable within your `mapIt` function.

Comment: Can you provide a little example of how the JSON looks?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto I just added some of the JSON file. I really only require the geometry coordinates and the "countries" value.

Comment: @bencripps I tried to return geo right outside of the for loop and getCountry is still saying geo is undefined.

Comment: do you mean to be setting `geo` to `val[i].geography.coordinates` at every iteration of the `getCountry()`? If not, then why the `$.each()` call?

Comment: @theoperatore no, you are correct I should not be setting geo.  I am using $.each because I need to eventually be able to loop through all of the "countries" values in the JSON file and check if one of the "countries" values matches a different value. I am still fairly new to JSON requests and using $.each so I will change that. thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to use Jquery? I think you don't

Comment: The biggest problem here is that you don't understand asynchronous callbacks. The code after your `getCountry()` call will run long before you give `geo` any value (so it will be working with a `geo` value of `undefined`), and the `return` statement in your callback doesn't do anything.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto I fail to see how that's relevant. And performing an AJAX request to retrieve JSON is considerably more involved without jQuery (or some other library).

Comment: As @JLRishe said You need a callback to be triggered when the promise is satisfied, but that is only part of your code I don't see that you analyze the Json properly...

Comment: He's talking about how `getCountry()` will run and the request for the ajax will be sent to retrieve your json file, but the code will continue to execute. When `geo` is used, the request will not be fulfilled yet, and `geo` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't seem to understand how asynchrony works. The code after your `getCountry()` call runs long before your `getJSON` callback does, so it is working with a `geo` value of `undefined`. I don't really understand what you are trying to do there when your JSON has multiple pairs of coordinates and you're only trying to actually use one, but here is how you could operate on just the first pair:

```
function getCountry(){
  $.getJSON('country.json', function(res) {
      var country = res.world[0],
          coords;
      if (country) {
          coords = country.geometry.coordinates;
          mapCoordinates(coords[0], coords[1]);
      }
  });
}

function mapCoordinates(lat, long) {
    $(".container").mapael({
        map : {
            name : "world_countries", // name of JS file
        },
        plots: {
            'Random': {
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: long
            }               
        }
    });
}

function mapIt() {
    getCountry();
}

mapIt();
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for clearing that up for me. I was only trying to use one as practice so that I could wrap my head around how the functions were working. I appreciate the help!